# Is it possible to pause and resume google map animateCamera method in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, animation

I have written a code where i do

```
map.animateCamera(mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("21.146372"), Double
                            .parseDouble("79.088041")), 14f), 2000, null);
```

This makes the map animate to the given location.

What I am trying to do is when the map is animating, can i have a button for pause and resume the animation process of the map?

Comment: no you can not , as far as I know , because when Ever the animation stops for example any dialog comes and pop up , so when the dialog would stop showing and map activity will start activity , then there are two possibilities that I have observed 1, Animation would simply end and map continuous
2. animation would get start again from the starting point